# How can I use Ember.Logger to get the same output as console.log?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logging, ember.js, console

I'm trying to get an understanding of why I would use `Ember.Logger` instead of just using `console.log` directly. The problem is, no matter where I log from (from any file), the output shows the log as emanating from:

```
ember.js?body=1:15359
```

Whereas, if I use console.log, I get a more helpful log location, including the file that logged and where in the file:

```
application.js?body=1:9
```

Is there a way to use Ember.Logger that would show the location and information? The docs indicate that one should "[o]verride this to provide more robust logging functionality." Should I just assume that this is supposed to be for overriding and making something really fancy and not just for basic logs to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, no, I don't think there is a way to have the Ember logger report the correct line numbers. Logging to the console is just a commonly implemented API, [it's not a Javascript standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console.log). Because of this, the browser automatically determines where a log statement came from and makes it pretty much impossible to wrap a layer of indirection around it. There might be some clever ticks out there, but none that I know of.

But more importantly, I don't think Ember's logger is really meant for third party consumption. It's mostly used internally by Ember, so the main reason you would override it is to redirect Ember's logging to a different location. In my opinion, it seems like a fairly poor way to handle your own application logging.